# How can I get intersection of line segments not lines?

Tags: geometry

I have something like this right now:

```
      //gets angle of intersection between two lines
       public string GetAngleOfIntersection(Line l1, Line l2)
       {
           double a = (float)l1.point1.x - l1.point2.x;
           double b = (float)l1.point1.y - l1.point2.y;
           double c = (float)l2.point1.x - l2.point2.x;
           double d = (float)l2.point1.y - l2.point2.y;

           double cos_angle, angle;
           double mag_v1 = Math.Sqrt(a * a + b * b);
           double mag_v2 = Math.Sqrt(c * c + d * d);
           cos_angle = (a*c +b*d)/(mag_v1 * mag_v2);

           angle = Mathf.Acos((float)cos_angle);
           angle = angle * 180 / (Math.PI);
           angle = Math.Round(angle, 2);

           string angleString = angle.ToString();

           return angleString;
       }
```

I am wondering how can I alter my function to find the angle of intersection of line segments not lines? Currently, it's lines.

Comment: If your line segments intersect, then the point of intersection is the same as the point of intersection of the lines. Perhaps you just need to check to see if the point of intersection you have found lies on your segments.

Comment: The only special case where the angles may *differ* is when you have line segmnts $AB$ and $AC$ with one common end point and the angle is obtuse

Comment: @tomi, I don't get the point of intersection above. I just get the angle. So, I have to get the point of intersection and then constrain it to points of line 1 and the points of line2?

Comment: The angle between segments = angle between lines

Comment: I have angle but not a point?

Comment: How can I check if the point of intersection lies on either line?